# Activity in portrait or reverse portrait only

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation

I want my activity to be available only in both portrait modes - portrait and reversePortrait. How can I achieve this? When I set `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` it will force activity to be only in normal portrait - vice versa with reversePortrait.

Please, don't tell me it's a bad approach to force/lock orientation. I know about it, but still client is requesting it. Thanks for understanding and for any ideas.

**UPDATE:** API Level 11 and higher

Comment: Not a bad approach IMO, some apps/games just won't work right in certain orientations.

Comment: Thanks Ricky, exactly. I just saw people arguing about that on similar posts so I wanted to clarify that I really need only portrait.

Comment: many e-commerce application too locks orientation

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you are on API level 9+, use `android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"`.

> Portrait orientation, but can be either normal or reverse portrait
>   based on the device sensor. Added in API level 9.

*[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen)*

Comment: Thank you!!! I must be blind that I missed that value! And yes, I'm on API 11+ so this works perfectly.

Comment: I had to use the typo-ed version "sensorPortait" on api 15.

Comment: This rotates the view alright but doesn't fire any event. I need to capture the event when orientation change from normal to reverse view. How to do that?

Comment: i need to listen to orientation change also along with sensorPortait, any sugesstions?

Comment: **NOTE** I couldn't get `sensorPortrait` to work properly. It would never support upside down Portrait (i.e. `reversePortrait`). However, using `fullSensor` did work but it had the caveat of also allowing landscape. That ended up being fine for me but if you only want `portrait` and `reversePortrait`, you can intercept the orientation change in your Activity with `onConfigurationChanged` and `newConfig.orientation` and just ignore or override landscape changes.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity's sake, I use this for backward compatibility...

```
public final class OrientationHelper {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    public static void setRequestedOrientationSensorPortrait(Activity activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
        } else {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    public static void setRequestedOrientationSensorLandscape(Activity activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
        } else {
            activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
    }
}
```

usage

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    OrientationHelper.setRequestedOrientationSensorPortrait(this);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait|reversePortrait"
android:configuration="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

In your `WhateverActivity.java`:

```
protected void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if(newConfig.orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ||
        newConfig.orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

You can try this :)

Comment: Thanks, this is a good answer but as I forgot to tell that I'm on API 11+ (Honeycomb) the alextc's answer is more suitable for me and works great. And I don't know why, but I got AAPT error when I try to use | in screenOrientation so I was not able to use two values but only one :(

Comment: @xjaphx, android:screenOrientation="portrait|reversePortrait". That doesn't work. The following error appears: "error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenOrientation' with value 'portrait|reversePortrait')".

Comment: @PaulAnnekov Thas't because it's a simple enum, so you can't use a combination of values using "|"