# Specify layout for portrait and reverse-portrait mode

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any way to specify one layout for portrait mode and another to reverse-portrait mode?

By portrait mode I mean that you rotate your device, for example, right (from landscape mode), and reverse-portrait mode - left.

So, my point is to make right side menu, that will alwayse be there (and buttons will just rotate). Or is there any better solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this manually with the following Code:

```
protected void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if(newConfig.orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT ||
    newConfig.orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
} }
```

as mentioned in [Activity in portrait or reverse portrait only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686512/activity-in-portrait-or-reverse-portrait-only)

Comment: I got the idea, but how to set different layout for reverse-portrait mode? This code just "turn off" landscape mode.

Comment: Also, onConfigurationChanged must be public

Comment: Well if the new config == Reverse you have to manually setContentView to your the specified reverst protrait layout.

Answer (score -1):

Create a folder layout-land and layout-port

You can find more information here :

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Yes, I know it. But with this solution there is no difference between portrait and reverse-portrait modes