# How to enable only portrait and reverse portrait in phones, "sensorPortrait" not working on phones?

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation, portrait

I cant figure out why setting "sensorPortrait" attribute in manifest for an activity doesn't work to allow the activity to go into reverse portrait. This is how I set in manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivty"
        android:label="Testing"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
        android:configChanges="orientation">
    </activity>
```

The above code is not working for me to get both reversePortrait and portrait on Moto E(4.4.4) or Galaxy S3(4.3), but I can confirm it works on a Nexus 7(5.0.1) tablet, I tried several other answers but this one seems to be the easiest and it is seemingly not working for me on 'phones', am I missing some information that is relevant for getting this to work?

I tried the following link which is just as similar as my question but nothing seems helpful regarding this

[Activity in portrait or reverse portrait only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686512/activity-in-portrait-or-reverse-portrait-only)

Currently with the flag "sensorPortrait" it behaves just like setting "portrait", in phones.

Comment: I have the same problem on Xperia Z2 and SDK Version 21 in manifest.
I never get a reversePortrait even if I enable all orientations.

What is your targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion ?

Comment: Actually as in my comment before to ianhanniballake, we can have reverse portrait, when we set the mode to "fullSensor", I just tested it in my Xperia Z2, running Lollipop 5.1.1, where I have my min sdk as 15 and target sdk as 23. They only problem is that in full sensor it will rotate in all directions.

Comment: Hmm, documentations says '**sensorPortrait**: Portrait orientation, but can be either normal or reverse portrait based on the device sensor'

But on '**fullSensor** is a note `some devices won't normally use reverse portrait or reverse landscape, but this enables those`.

So the quesion is, How to enable ONLY the Portrait and reversePortrait on devices what normaly not use reverve Views.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [PhoneWindowManager source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/policy/PhoneWindowManager.java#5886), you can see that it checks for the internal value `config_allowAllRotations` and uses that to determine if the 180 degree rotation (i.e., reverse portrait on phones) is allowed.

With a [default value to false](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/config.xml#598), this means that reverse portrait is disabled on phones. You'll note that the [sw600dp value](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values-sw600dp/config.xml#32) (i.e., tablets) is true, hence why you can use all rotations including reverse portrait on tablet devices.

Comment: What you say makes sense but then again if I set android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" reverse portrait will happen even in phones. Infact all 4 rotations happen without issues for that particular orientation mode, so what do you think happens there, does it ignore whatever the internal value has?