# Android - 'sensorPortrait' orientation not working

Tags: android

I have come across a problem where the orientation `sensorPortrait` does not work, i have tried enabling both through the manifest and within the activity itself with

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
```

But this seems to just be locked in normal portrait mode, however if i try `fullSensor'

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
```

which according to the docs

> The orientation is determined by the device orientation sensor for any of the 4 orientations. This is similar to "sensor" except this allows any of the 4 possible screen orientations, regardless of what the device will normally do (for example, some devices won't normally use reverse portrait or reverse landscape, but this enables those). Added in API level 9.

and it does exactly that, all 4 orientations are possible. If i also try

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);
```

I am able to achieve reverse portrait, which leads me back to my original question, why does `sensorPortrait` not work? It looks like it has something to do with this line from the docs for `fullSensor'

> regardless of what the device will normally do (for example, some devices won't normally use reverse portrait or reverse landscape, but this enables those)

So how do i enable it, is that possible and why does `fullSensor` seem to override it but not `sensorPortrait`? I can't seem to find any mention of how to do so. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079024/how-to-enable-only-portrait-and-reverse-portrait-in-phones-sensorportrait-not) suggests that the `PhoneWindowManager` is responsible for this.

Is the ideal solution just to create an `OrientationEventListener()` and manually call `setRequestedOrientation()` manually depending on the values returned via `onOrientationChanged(int orientation)`?

Comment: SAME HERE! On my MOTO 4, I couldn't get `sensorPortrait` to work properly. It would never support upside down Portrait (i.e. `reversePortrait`). However, using `fullSensor` did work but it had the caveat of also allowing landscape. That ended up being fine for me but if you only want `portrait` and `reversePortrait`, you can intercept the orientation change in your Activity with `onConfigurationChanged` and `newConfig.orientation` and just ignore or override landscape changes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a work around i have created a `SensorPortraitActivity`:

```
public class SensorPortraitActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PORTRAIT = 0;
    private static final int REVERSE_PORTRAIT = 180;
    private static final int OFFSET = 45;
    private static final int UNKNOWN = -1;

//  account for 0 = 360 (eg. -1 = 359)
    private static final int PORTRAIT_START = PORTRAIT - OFFSET + 360; 
    private static final int PORTRAIT_END = PORTRAIT + OFFSET;
    private static final int REVERSE_PORTRAIT_START = REVERSE_PORTRAIT - OFFSET;
    private static final int REVERSE_PORTRAIT_END = REVERSE_PORTRAIT + OFFSET;

    private OrientationChangeListener mListener;
    private OrientationEventListener mOrientationListener;
    private CurrentOrientation mCurrentOrientation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mOrientationListener = new OrientationEventListener(this) {
            @Override
            public void onOrientationChanged(int i) {
                orientationChanged(i);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mOrientationListener.enable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mOrientationListener.disable();
    }

    //optional 
    public void setOrientationChangeListener(OrientationChangeListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    private void orientationChanged(int degrees) {

        if (degrees != UNKNOWN){

            if (degrees >= PORTRAIT_START || degrees <= PORTRAIT_END){

                if (mCurrentOrientation != CurrentOrientation.PORTRAIT){

                    mCurrentOrientation = CurrentOrientation.PORTRAIT;
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

                if (mListener != null){
                    mListener.onPortrait();
                }
            }
        } else if (degrees >= REVERSE_PORTRAIT_START && degrees <= REVERSE_PORTRAIT_END){

            if (mCurrentOrientation != CurrentOrientation.REVERSE_PORTRAIT){

                mCurrentOrientation = CurrentOrientation.REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);

                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.onReversePortrait();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    interface OrientationChangeListener {
        void onPortrait();
        void onReversePortrait();
    }

    enum CurrentOrientation {
        PORTRAIT, REVERSE_PORTRAIT
    }
}
```

Although it does seem like overkill for something as simple as this.

To use it simple `extend SensorPortraitActivity`

```
public class ExampleActivity extends SensorPortraitActivity implements SensorPortraitView.OrientationChangeListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //set listener if you want callbacks
        super.setOrientationChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPortrait() {
        //portrait orientation
    }

    @Override
    public void onReversePortrait() {
        //reverse portrait orientation
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that really works for this issue that I have seen. Have done a similar thing myself now as sensorPortrait just doesnt do what is expected of it! This also seems to react quicker on rotation as well which is a bonus. Thanks for sharing.