# Why "screenOrientation=sensorPortrait" in AndroidManifest.xml doesn't work?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, screen-orientation

I want my activity to support "portrait" and "reversePortrait" modes and I found in the documentation that "sensorPortrait" is what I need. But this doesn't rotate my activity in "reversePortrait" mode.

AndroidManifest.xml of MainActivity:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" 
android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
```

Does somebody know what is the problem and maybe I can do it the other way?

Comment: try  `android:screenOrientation=["portrait" | "reversePortrait"]`

Comment: Just use: `android:screenOrientation=value` in the activity manifest which you want to set the screen orientation

Comment: Nero, this is a compilation error, I cant't do like that

Comment: Gourav, yes, I did like that. But the value "sensorPortrait" doesn't work right

Comment: it might be a odd one but can you try using `sensorPortait` instead of `sensorPortrait`. Let me know if this works and I'll explain why...

Comment: Nero, unfortunately that didn't help me

Comment: @Igor which device are you using

Comment: I'm using 3 different devices with Android Emulator: Pixel (API: 28), Nexus One(API:24), Nexus 5X(API:28). And it doen't work on none of them.

Comment: @Igor Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174723/android-sensorportrait-orientation-not-working

Comment: @AmanRawat , thank you for your help! But do you know why the simple “sensorPortrait” mode doesn’t work and I have to customize this by myself like in the link you provided?

Comment: @Igor Don't know the exact reason but it happened to me once. If the above solution worked for you please accept and upvote the answer.