# Portrait mode only with rotation

Tags: android

Please how do I rotate the screen in portrait mode only. In this case I want the screen to rotate when the user turns the device upside down while maintaining portrait mode.
I have tried all the following settings in the manifest file without any different result. All seem to produce the same thing. What am I missing please?

```
android:screenOrientation ="Portrait"
android:screenOrientation ="userPortrait"
android:screenOrientation ="sensorPortrait"
```

sensorportrait doesn't work in my case though it appears to be the accepted answer. Do I need to do anything else aside that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686512/activity-in-portrait-or-reverse-portrait-only

Comment: thanks for the link but like I stated earlier sensorPortrait doesn't work when I flip the device in reverse portrait.

Comment: There's more to that link than that one line of code.