# Make android app to work in portrait or reverse portrait only

Tags: android, orientation, portrait

I am working on android app and wish to make this app work only in portrait or reverse portrait mode. In the manifest file I mentioned screen orientation value as "sensorPortrait" but app works only in portrait mode, i.e., if I hold my phone upside down, nothing changes in my app. Although, I do have other apps on my phone that work in both portrait and reverse portrait mode. I have seen similar question asked before but suggestion given don't work as those questions were asked way back and suggestion given might not be a good answer anymore. Any recommendations? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activity in portrait or reverse portrait only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686512/activity-in-portrait-or-reverse-portrait-only)

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686512/activity-in-portrait-or-reverse-portrait-only?noredirect=1&lq=1) it should works.

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your AndroidManifest.xml file, you need to configure the  to use the orientation from the sensor. This should be the default, but you can force it to the sensor's orientations, for all 4 possible orientations, with android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"

```
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"/>
```

Comment: "fullSensor" lets app run in landscape mode. I only need portrait and reverse portrait mode.

Comment: yes I notice that. Let me read some stuff. If I found some inserting I'll get back to you.